# bind the button content which textbox has the cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to create On-screen keyboard.

[image]

Here i want to bind the button content, which textbox has the cursor.

```
public partial class current_cursor : Window
{
    public current_cursor()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();     

    }

    private void btn_a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_diplay_1.Text += btn_a.Content;
    }

}
```

with above code i can only bind the button content in first textbox.

but i can't bind the value in another textbox.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation in WPF:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Margin="30,28,128,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" GotFocus="textBox1_GotFocus" />
<TextBox Height="23" Margin="58,86,100,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top"  GotFocus="textBox2_GotFocus"/>
```

**Backend:**

```
 Control ctrl = null;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
            tb.Text += Convert.ToString(button1.Content);
        }
    }


    private void textBox2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ctrl = (Control)sender;
    }

    private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ctrl = (Control)sender;
    }
```

Comment: i am so sorry MSUH. there is no Enter event for textbox.i hope you can resolve this problem. please help me...

Comment: Sorry Chandru, I thought your question is related to C# only, I have now edited the solution, it will work in WPF.

Comment: Hoang please take a look to these links .stackoverflow.com/questions/10880229/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/10877616/…. i posted a questioh here.i hope that you only right person to resolve that problem... please do this fever..

Answer (score 1):

Write a multi value converter that has two textboxes as parameters and the convert method returns the value of the active textbox (that has focus)

Bind the button content using multi value converter you just wrote.

Comment: i can't get it. please Hasan Khan, explain with your code what you are trying to tell me.